# Interactive Brokers API placingOrder in Wrapper function causes disconnect

Tags: java, swing

I am using the Java API and I've made a simple Swing GUI with a push button. When I push the button it executes:

```
anInstance.connection.reqRealTimeBars(id, contract, 5,"TRADES",false); 
// note that connection = new EClientSocket(Wrapper) which is assigned in constructor`
```

which causes my overrided Wrapper function realtimeBar to execute.

I use Joda Time and `getSecondOfMinute` to convert the Time in the wrapper function into what second it is. If it is 55 seconds, I want to place a trade. (I.e. I want my program to place a trade every minute at the 55 second mark).

However whenever I place the trade, there is something which disconnects my connection with the API.

I think it might have to do with synchronization and perhaps some deadlock? Anyways, the error closes my connection to the API which is not what I want since the point of my program is to trade constantly.

Does anyone know why this issue is coming up? More importantly, how do I get around this?

Sample Code

someWrapper.java which overrides EWrapper:

```
public class someWrapper implements EWrapper {
    private IBProgram anInstance;

public void setReference(IBProgram anInstance){
    this.anInstance = anInstance    
 }

// overide and implement various EWrapper methods. 
// The Ewrapper method below is a sample of placing an Order 
// causing problems in an EWrapper method

public void updatePortfolio(Contract contract, int position, double marketPrice, double marketValue,
        double averageCost, double unrealizedPNL, double realizedPNL, String accountName){

Order myFakeOrder = new Order();
Contract myFakeContract = new Contract();
myFakeContract.m_symbol = "GOOG";
myFakeContract.m_exchange = "SMART";
myFakeContract.m_secType = "STK";
myFakeContract.m_currency = "USD";
myFakeOrder.m_action = "BUY";
myFakeOrder.m_totalQuantity = 1;
myFakeOrder.m_orderType = "LMT";
myFakeOrder.m_lmtPrice = 1;
myFakeOrder.m_tif = "DAY";
anInstance.connection.placeOrder(2124124,myFakeContract,myFakeOrder);
}
}
```

IBProgram.java

```
public class IBProgram {
 someWrapper wrapper;
 public EClientSocket connection;

 public IBProgram() {

 this.wrapper = new someWrapper();
 this.connection = new EClientSocket(wrapper);
 }
}
```

GUI

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame{
     private IBProgram IBProgramInstance;

public GUI(){
     initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
     myButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
     myButton.setText("Start Trading");
     myButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            myButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
}

public void setReference(IBProgram Instance){
      this.IBProgramInstance = Instance;
}

private void myButtonActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
          IBProgramInstance.connection.reqAccountUpdates(true,"myaccountid");
}

public static void main(String args[]){
       IBProgram IBPInstance = new IBProgram();
       IBProgramInstance.wrapper.setReference(IBPInstance);
       IBProgram.connection.eConnect("127.0.0.1",7496,12);
       GUI guiInstance = new GUI();
       guiInstance.setReference(IBPInstance);
       guiInstance.setVisible(true);

}
```

Adding Error Message

```
Exception in thread "EReader" java.lang.Error: Interrupted attempt to aquire write lock
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(AbstractDocument.java:1349)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:659)
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(JTextComponent.java:1718)
at IBconnect.IBTradeGui.setConnectionText(IBTradeGui.java:698)
at IBconnect.someWrapper.connectionClosed(someWrapper.java:63)
at com.ib.client.EClientSocket.close(EClientSocket.java:2004)
at com.ib.client.EReader.run(EReader.java:78)
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @perissf Lol. Well I just wrote the above to demonstrate the problem I was having placing an order through a wrapper. I don't actually trade based on portfolio updates. I definitely have a lack of programming xp but I'm trying to learn. What would you recommend I change? Also I've added an error message that I'm getting can you please advise?

Comment: @perissf I commented out the relevant section where I setConnectionText and I still have the disconnection problem.

Comment: Looks like a swing problem. I suggest to retag the question by adding swing (and removing jodatime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since most of the Swing objects are not thread safe, you have to create the `GUI` instance using this code in the `main()` method:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        GUI guiInstance = new GUI();
    }
});
```

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (and the following page) for further information about Swing thread safety and the Event Dispatch Thread (AKA EDT).

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, pay more attention to use Uppercase names for classes, and camelCase names for class instances. Avoid public properties in classes, because they violate the encapsulation principle. Catch all exceptions in the class implementing `EWrapper`, otherwise IB will close the connection. And more importantly, pay a lot of attention when you insert orders in the `updatePortfolio()` method or any other method overriding the methods of `EWrapper` interface, because they are triggered by IB socket and you never know when they are invoked.

Comment: the snippet didn't solve my problem unfortunately, but it did at least define the problem. For example I know for sure it is a Swing issue because I tried recreating my program without a gui and it works fine. I couldn't figure out a way to fix issue though because `invokeLater` didn't work. Neither did creating an instance of the event dispatch thread and posting events to it a la this link http://www.kauss.org/Stephan/swing/index.html

Comment: Instead I decided to make a console only trading program for now and work on a GUI version later. Also thanks for the accepted Java practices. It's hard to pick those up sometimes when you are developing by yourself...

Comment: If you need a working example of a Swing GUI working with IB API, use and study the sample application shippen within the API package

Comment: thanks for the help. You were actually right with your original comment about it being something with openOrder or OrderStatus. I had a snippet of code there that referenced a variable that wasn't initialized yet so I was getting null pointers. In my errors I hadn't done a `Logger` yet so all that it said when data spat out was nullpointer without telling me where. Once I added the logger I was able to determine where the error occured and I can't believe it was something so silly and unrelated to what I thought was the issue. Anyways, thx for your help & advice on accepted practices